# Is there a way to check whether a point is within the convex hull of an object?

Tags: mesh, geometry

I'm trying to calculate to what extent one object contains another in a blender scene. To do this it would be ideal to see if one object is contained in the convex hull of another.

I realise there are simpler less precise ways of doing this using bounding boxes, and I also realize doing calculations with convex hulls can be computationally heavy but I was wondering if something existed?

All I have found so far are methods for generating the convex hull of a single object [here](https://michelanders.blogspot.com/2012/02/3d-convex-hull-in-python-blender.html) but I can't see an easy way of repurposing these for checking the relationship between two objects